# Define hive-jdbc JNDI data source on WebSphere - any updates?

Tags: hive, websphere, jndi

this is from febuary 2017:

[Define hive-jdbc JNDI data source on WebSphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050900/define-hive-jdbc-jndi-data-source-on-websphere)

the solution is feasible, but i was wandering whether the latest WebSphear version has a built-in solution

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define hive-jdbc JNDI data source on WebSphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050900/define-hive-jdbc-jndi-data-source-on-websphere)

Comment: Welcome to SO... things like this you can ask in the original question or start a bounty. To ask the question a second time is not a good practice here.

Answer (score 3):

The latest WebSphere Application Server traditional does not have a built-in solution, and the referenced approach still applies there.

However, if using WebSphere Application Server Liberty, it is fully supported to use a javax.sql.DataSource. Refer to the following knowledge center page,

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html

For example (Liberty only),

```
<dataSource id="hive-datasource" jndiName="jdbc/MyDataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="HiveJDBC" javax.sql.DataSource="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDataSource"/>
    <properties /> <!-- add key/value pairs to properties -->
</dataSource>

<library id="HiveJDBC">
  <file name="C:/jdbcdrivers/hive-jdbc.jar"/>
</library>
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built-in Hive JDBC support for WebSphere Application Server, so the question you referenced from back in Feb is still valid and current.